# Do chromebook-updates also patch hardware issues?

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

I recently read about a vulnerability in Mediatek-chipsets (https://research.checkpoint.com/2021/looking-for-vulnerabilities-in-mediatek-audio-dsp/). My chromebook has such a chipset. A solution is found and a patch available, but I'm wondering whether hardware-fixes also come with the Chromebookupdates provided by Google. Or are these just ChromeOS-related?

Comment: Hardware security issues can sometimes be addressed by software patches - see info on Meltdown, which affected Intel processors & was patched mainly in software - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(security_vulnerability)

Comment: That is an interesting question.  That would be a question to ask your ChromeBook's manufacturer, perhaps in their support forum.  It comes down to who is ultimately responsible for writing the driver: MediaTek, the manufacturer of the Chromebook, or Google.  I have had software issue on a server from Dell with an Adaptec RAID controller that was certified by Red Hat.  Each one said the others were responsible for fixing it.  However, we told Dell you certified it and we paid you, fix it or we return the server.  They just ended up sending us another RAID controller that did what we needed.